# Implementing a better FolderDialog for WPF

Tags: wpf

In WinForms we have used the following code for browsing folders - whenever supported by the OS, it uses the newer Vista style folder dialog:

```
// http://www.lyquidity.com/devblog/?p=136

using ShareX.HelpersLib.Properties;
using System;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ShareX.HelpersLib
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Wraps System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog to make it present
    /// a vista-style dialog.
    /// </summary>
    public class FolderSelectDialog : IDisposable
    {
        // Wrapped dialog
        private OpenFileDialog ofd;

        /// <summary>
        /// Default constructor
        /// </summary>
        public FolderSelectDialog()
        {
            ofd = new OpenFileDialog();

            ofd.Filter = "Folders|\n";
            ofd.AddExtension = false;
            ofd.CheckFileExists = false;
            ofd.DereferenceLinks = true;
            ofd.Multiselect = false;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets/Sets the initial folder to be selected. A null value selects the current directory.
        /// </summary>
        public string InitialDirectory
        {
            get
            {
                return ofd.InitialDirectory;
            }
            set
            {
                ofd.InitialDirectory = string.IsNullOrEmpty(value) ? Environment.CurrentDirectory : value;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets/Sets the title to show in the dialog
        /// </summary>
        public string Title
        {
            get
            {
                return ofd.Title;
            }
            set
            {
                ofd.Title = string.IsNullOrEmpty(value) ? Resources.FolderSelectDialog_Title_Select_a_folder : value;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the selected folder
        /// </summary>
        public string FileName
        {
            get
            {
                return ofd.FileName;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Shows the dialog
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>True if the user presses OK else false</returns>
        public bool ShowDialog()
        {
            return ShowDialog(NativeMethods.GetActiveWindow());
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Shows the dialog
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="hWndOwner">Handle of the control to be parent</param>
        /// <returns>True if the user presses OK else false</returns>
        public bool ShowDialog(IntPtr hWndOwner)
        {
            bool flag;

            if (Helpers.IsWindowsVistaOrGreater())
            {
                Reflector r = new Reflector("System.Windows.Forms");

                uint num = 0;
                Type typeIFileDialog = r.GetType("FileDialogNative.IFileDialog");
                object dialog = r.Call(ofd, "CreateVistaDialog");
                r.Call(ofd, "OnBeforeVistaDialog", dialog);

                uint options = (uint)r.CallAs(typeof(FileDialog), ofd, "GetOptions");
                options |= (uint)r.GetEnum("FileDialogNative.FOS", "FOS_PICKFOLDERS");
                r.CallAs(typeIFileDialog, dialog, "SetOptions", options);

                object pfde = r.New("FileDialog.VistaDialogEvents", ofd);
                object[] parameters = new object[] { pfde, num };
                r.CallAs2(typeIFileDialog, dialog, "Advise", parameters);
                num = (uint)parameters[1];
                try
                {
                    int num2 = (int)r.CallAs(typeIFileDialog, dialog, "Show", hWndOwner);
                    flag = 0 == num2;
                }
                finally
                {
                    r.CallAs(typeIFileDialog, dialog, "Unadvise", num);
                    GC.KeepAlive(pfde);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                using (FolderBrowserDialog fbd = new FolderBrowserDialog())
                {
                    fbd.Description = Title;
                    fbd.SelectedPath = InitialDirectory;
                    if (fbd.ShowDialog(new WindowWrapper(hWndOwner)) != DialogResult.OK) return false;
                    ofd.FileName = fbd.SelectedPath;
                    flag = true;
                }
            }

            return flag;
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            if (ofd != null)
            {
                ofd.Dispose();
            }
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates IWin32Window around an IntPtr
    /// </summary>
    internal class WindowWrapper : IWin32Window
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Constructor
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="handle">Handle to wrap</param>
        public WindowWrapper(IntPtr handle)
        {
            _hwnd = handle;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Original ptr
        /// </summary>
        public IntPtr Handle
        {
            get
            {
                return _hwnd;
            }
        }

        private IntPtr _hwnd;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// This class is from the Front-End for Dosbox and is used to present a 'vista' dialog box to select folders.
    /// Being able to use a vista style dialog box to select folders is much better then using the shell folder browser.
    /// http://code.google.com/p/fed/
    ///
    /// Example:
    /// var r = new Reflector("System.Windows.Forms");
    /// </summary>
    internal class Reflector
    {
        #region variables

        private string m_ns;
        private Assembly m_asmb;

        #endregion variables

        #region Constructors

        /// <summary>
        /// Constructor
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="ns">The namespace containing types to be used</param>
        public Reflector(string ns)
            : this(ns, ns)
        {
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Constructor
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="an">A specific assembly name (used if the assembly name does not tie exactly with the namespace)</param>
        /// <param name="ns">The namespace containing types to be used</param>
        public Reflector(string an, string ns)
        {
            m_ns = ns;
            m_asmb = null;
            foreach (AssemblyName aN in Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetReferencedAssemblies())
            {
                if (aN.FullName.StartsWith(an))
                {
                    m_asmb = Assembly.Load(aN);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        #endregion Constructors

        #region Methods

        /// <summary>
        /// Return a Type instance for a type 'typeName'
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="typeName">The name of the type</param>
        /// <returns>A type instance</returns>
        public Type GetType(string typeName)
        {
            Type type = null;
            string[] names = typeName.Split('.');

            if (names.Length > 0)
                type = m_asmb.GetType(m_ns + "." + names[0]);

            for (int i = 1; i < names.Length; ++i)
            {
                type = type.GetNestedType(names[i], BindingFlags.NonPublic);
            }
            return type;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Create a new object of a named type passing along any params
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="name">The name of the type to create</param>
        /// <param name="parameters"></param>
        /// <returns>An instantiated type</returns>
        public object New(string name, params object[] parameters)
        {
            Type type = GetType(name);

            ConstructorInfo[] ctorInfos = type.GetConstructors();
            foreach (ConstructorInfo ci in ctorInfos)
            {
                try
                {
                    return ci.Invoke(parameters);
                }
                catch
                {
                }
            }

            return null;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Calls method 'func' on object 'obj' passing parameters 'parameters'
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="obj">The object on which to excute function 'func'</param>
        /// <param name="func">The function to execute</param>
        /// <param name="parameters">The parameters to pass to function 'func'</param>
        /// <returns>The result of the function invocation</returns>
        public object Call(object obj, string func, params object[] parameters)
        {
            return Call2(obj, func, parameters);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Calls method 'func' on object 'obj' passing parameters 'parameters'
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="obj">The object on which to excute function 'func'</param>
        /// <param name="func">The function to execute</param>
        /// <param name="parameters">The parameters to pass to function 'func'</param>
        /// <returns>The result of the function invocation</returns>
        public object Call2(object obj, string func, object[] parameters)
        {
            return CallAs2(obj.GetType(), obj, func, parameters);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Calls method 'func' on object 'obj' which is of type 'type' passing parameters 'parameters'
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="type">The type of 'obj'</param>
        /// <param name="obj">The object on which to excute function 'func'</param>
        /// <param name="func">The function to execute</param>
        /// <param name="parameters">The parameters to pass to function 'func'</param>
        /// <returns>The result of the function invocation</returns>
        public object CallAs(Type type, object obj, string func, params object[] parameters)
        {
            return CallAs2(type, obj, func, parameters);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Calls method 'func' on object 'obj' which is of type 'type' passing parameters 'parameters'
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="type">The type of 'obj'</param>
        /// <param name="obj">The object on which to excute function 'func'</param>
        /// <param name="func">The function to execute</param>
        /// <param name="parameters">The parameters to pass to function 'func'</param>
        /// <returns>The result of the function invocation</returns>
        public object CallAs2(Type type, object obj, string func, object[] parameters)
        {
            MethodInfo methInfo = type.GetMethod(func, BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
            return methInfo.Invoke(obj, parameters);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Returns the value of property 'prop' of object 'obj'
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="obj">The object containing 'prop'</param>
        /// <param name="prop">The property name</param>
        /// <returns>The property value</returns>
        public object Get(object obj, string prop)
        {
            return GetAs(obj.GetType(), obj, prop);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Returns the value of property 'prop' of object 'obj' which has type 'type'
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="type">The type of 'obj'</param>
        /// <param name="obj">The object containing 'prop'</param>
        /// <param name="prop">The property name</param>
        /// <returns>The property value</returns>
        public object GetAs(Type type, object obj, string prop)
        {
            PropertyInfo propInfo = type.GetProperty(prop, BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
            return propInfo.GetValue(obj, null);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Returns an enum value
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="typeName">The name of enum type</param>
        /// <param name="name">The name of the value</param>
        /// <returns>The enum value</returns>
        public object GetEnum(string typeName, string name)
        {
            Type type = GetType(typeName);
            FieldInfo fieldInfo = type.GetField(name);
            return fieldInfo.GetValue(null);
        }

        #endregion Methods
    }
}
```

Using reflector methods, it the folder selection dialog based on the System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog in WinForms. Similarly, we should be able to implement a folder dialog based on Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog.

e.g.

```
Reflector r = new Reflector("Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog");
```

I would like to attempt this but I was wondering if a similar attempt has been done before.

I'd also like to know any pointers in the right director to query certain string based parameters e.g.

```
r.GetType("FileDialogNative.IFileDialog");
```

These don't look exposed unless you have a specific tool to query these.

Thanks and regards
Michael

Comment: Check out code project I'm pretty sure there's a WPF file and or folder dialog already there.

Comment: There is, however, none of them are based on Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog